# Changing the REPRESENTS SUBSIDIARY field in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I wish to change the subsidiary which is being represented by a certain entity, as I have used a dummy subsidiary before.

Is there a way to do this? I cannot change the field via the UI and I cannot find the field in the import functionality

Comment: Is this for Netsuite One World?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the "subsidiary" field in the UI by completing the following: go to a entity record in edit mode, un-layer all tabs (or add "&unlayered=T" to the url bar), use the browser Find feature (normally Ctrl + F) and search for subsidiary.  If it does not come up this way identify the form used and open that for editing, un-layer all tabs, and use the find feature for subsidiary, elect to show or change the display settings then return to the record in edit mode to change.

OR via suitescript, if you have the field id (if native/standard NetSuite field id = subsidiary) you can run the following code in the browser console

```
require(['N/record'], function(record){
  var Ids = [ 
    //enter all entity internal ids here
  ];
  for (var i=0; i<Ids.length; i++){
    record.submitFields({
      type: record.Type.______, //ref Suite Answer Id: 45161 
      id: Ids[i],
      values: {
        subsidiary: 1 //the internal id for the subsidiary you want to set
      },
      options: {
        enableSourcing: false,  //default is true
        ignoreMandatoryFields : true //default is false
      }
    });
    console.log('done', 'updated id: '+Ids[i]);
  }
  console.log('done', '# of records updated: '+i);
});
```

OR you can try Mass Updates (ref Suite Answer [8429](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8429/kw/8429)), or CSV Imports (ref Suite Answer [10022](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10022/kw/10022)).